# Sublime link command error when run python?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublime-build

I am having link command error with sublime when I am trying to run python scripts. It used to work fine.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Documents/sideproj/IoT/one_hot_encoding.py, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x0A 0x69 0x6D 0x70 0x6F 0x72 0x74 0x20 0x74 0x65 0x6E 0x73 0x6F 0x72 0x66 0x6C ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/Documents/sideproj/IoT/one_hot_encoding.py
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

EIDT:
Thanks it is because I didn't choose the right mode in the tools->build systems.

Comment: are you sure it's not running a compiler for another language? this really seems like it's trying to compile c++.

Comment: How are you running the scripts?

Comment: As @Axium mentioned, it looks like you have the wrong build system selected. Check in `Tools > Build System` and make sure that either ` Python` or `Automatic` is selected.